# opencv's findCirclesdGrid behaves differently in C++ than in python?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am porting some python code using opencv to C++. I am having trouble with the camera calibration stage. The python code is able to find circles on my grid, but when I call (seemingly) identical calls using C++, the call to `findCirclesGrid` seems to hang. I confirmed that my input images after some prepping (median blur and grey scale) are identical (printed them out and used beyond compare). I also checked that all the fields in the `params` struct are identical. Furthermore, I used the blob detector to run `detect` on the input images and the results from both languages are identical there as well. Both my python environment and my C++ project are loading opencv 4.6.0.

Just as a sanity check, I also ran the python code on the exported 'grey' image rendered by opencv in C++---probably not very meaningful since I verified that these images are identical between the 2 languages. However, as expected, the python code returned a nice healthy grid of 25x25 circles on that image.

Here is the code (image loading excluded).

Python:

```
params = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.1
detector = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
blur = cv.medianBlur(img,3)
grey = cv.cvtColor(blur, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grid_size = [25,25]
retval, centers = cv.findCirclesGrid(grey, grid_size, cv.CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC, blobDetector=detector)
```

C++

```
cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
params.filterByCircularity = true;
params.minCircularity = .1;
bool ret = false;
auto blobDetector = cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
cv::Mat blur;
cv::Mat grey;
cv::medianBlur(image, blur, 3);
cv::cvtColor(blur, grey, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Size gridSize(25, 25);
std::vector<cv::Point2f> imagePoints;
ret = cv::findCirclesGrid(grey, gridSize, cv::Mat(imagePoints), cv::CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC_GRID, blobDetector);
```

I saw some activity on the opencv repo having to do with `findCirclesGrid` hanging (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/19079/commits/175cd03ff2237eca57089f14f866fe17186130b4), but that was a few version ago---and besides, the underlying libraries should be identical in both languages. I am also confused as to why the `detect` code can find all the visible blobs, but in the case of the C++ implementation `findCirclesGrid` never returns.

Here is the input image (reduced by 50%):
[image]

Comment: Hi dmedine, just curious how you resolved the issue (in a previous post- I can't seem to find it now) where you were actually getting different blob results between Python and C++?

Comment: question looks very familiar. [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76504021/opencv-blob-detection-results-differ-between-c-and-python) was deleted by author. -- those algorithms may contain some nondeterminism. -- check argument order, use keyword arguments in python

Comment: also posted on the OpenCV forum: https://forum.opencv.org/t/findcirclesgrid-hangs-in-c-but-not-python/13600

Comment: your question's title says they differ in behavior, but then in the question body you reveal that one actually HANGS, which isn't just differing behavior.

Comment: @gremto, there was a typo in the previous post, the wrong matrix was being fed to `detect` in the cpp version. I voted to have it closed as a typo and then deleted it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you have enough rep points to edit a post if you think it requires it.

Comment: I'm not clairvoyant nor can I read your thoughts. if I went by the question body and "fixed" the title, that too would be wrong, because the top voted answer directly contradicts your assertion that anything "hangs". this is up to you to clarify.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I edited the post to say that it 'seems to hang'. Anyway, I don't really see how a process in one language 'seems to hang' and the other one performing at a reasonable speed does not qualify as a different behavior. I can't read your mind either, so I don't really know what your gripe is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not hang. It is processing and it takes some time. Your board has lots of points and your program has been asked to find a grid of 25 by 25 circles which has many possible combinations inside your pattern.
The only problem with you code is that you do not need to cast the vector of points when detecting the circles. That outputs the following error:

OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
OpenCV(4.5.1-pre) Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == Size(_cols, _rows)) in cv::_OutputArray::create, file ......\modules\core\src\matrix_wrap.cpp, line 1188

**Here is a fully working code:**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image;
    image = cv::imread("circles.png");
    cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
    params.filterByCircularity = true;
    params.minCircularity = .1;
    bool ret = false;
    auto blobDetector = cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
    cv::Mat blur;
    cv::Mat grey;
    cv::medianBlur(image, blur, 3);
    cv::cvtColor(blur, grey, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::Size gridSize(25, 25);
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> imagePoints;
    std::cout << "Detecting circles." << std::endl; 
    ret = cv::findCirclesGrid( grey, gridSize, imagePoints);// cv::CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC_GRID, blobDetector);

    if (ret)
    {
        std::cout << "Pattern found!" << std::endl;
        cv::drawChessboardCorners(image, gridSize, cv::Mat(imagePoints), ret);
        cv::namedWindow("image", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
        cv::imshow("image", image);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
    else std::cout << "Pattern not found!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Here is the produced image:**
[image]

Comment: you are right. I was being hasty. I thought the cpp was hanging because it takes a very, very long time process the image (I went to lunch yesterday and it was still processing), whereas in python it takes ~1 minute to achieve this. They shouldn't differ so long in processing time. I will check my optimization flags on my opencv project and build again.

Comment: The problem turns out to be that I was running in debug mode. In Release mode, this works reasonably fast (about as fast as my python code did). I didn't expect the Debug optimization settings to slow it down ~500x and thought something was wrong.